# How can I use dot.tk domain with GitHub Pages?

Tags: http, github, github-pages

I have registered a free domain from dot.tk, but I want to link it with github pages:

> [username.github.io/PROname/v1/](http://el3zahaby.github.io/URLShort/v2.1/)

to

> [PROname.tk](http://dot.tk)

I have seen this document: https://help.github.com/articles/quick-start-setting-up-a-custom-domain, but that's not sufficiently helpful with my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the best way to do this is changing your dns provider. Just create an account at http://cloudflare.com/ and add your domain there.

You can add a Cname record to point the dns server to your username.github.io and everything will work perfectly

See my own website:
[image: example]

Answer (score 19):

Steps:

1. Login to freenom.com
2. Go to Services -> My Domains -> Manage Domain
3. Management Tools -> Nameservers
4. Select **Use default nameservers (Freenom Nameservers)**
5. Now Go To Manage Freenom DNS

Set as per Below Image.

**Note:**
The IP addresses mentioned in the screenshot are outdated. When setting A records, use the IP addresses mentioned in [Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain)

[image: See the Image]

Comment: This works! Before I added 185.199.108.153...185.199.111.153. But those for IPs didn't work. But adding 192.30.252.153 and 192.30.252.154 is working :) thanks @Rahul and Praveen Kumar

Comment: @hyukkyulee you have to use your github ip's, for eg I have mentioned my ip's.

Comment: other tutorial had different/outdated GitHub ips, but the ips you mentioned are still good :) thanks!

Comment: new github IP's 185.199.108.153, 185.199.109.153, 185.199.110.153, 185.199.111.153 . Can be found on new IPs on the following link https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you know if it's somehow possible to use username.github.io/subpath1 as the target for www.mydomain1.tk , and username.github.io/subpath2 as the target for www.mydomain2.tk ?